# Where to host my own DokuWiki on a stick

Tags: dokuwiki

I have a [DokuWiki on a stick](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki_on_a_stick) (basically DokuWiki only ... uhmm, it's on a stick) in which I've been gathering ... stuff (*my gawd, is this guy specific or what? :)* and now I'd like to put it somewhere on a web. What would be a good place to host it so I can access it from anywhere?

Is it possible maybe to host it on Google Apps of my company, and how would that process go?

I'd welcome all experiences and advices on the subject.

*Btw, I've no idea whether this should go here or on S.User.*

Answer (score 1):

Given that DokuWiki is written in PHP, you can't just host it on something static like Dropbox or GitHub Pages the way you can with TiddlyWiki.

There are various free PHP hosts out there that you can search up and some of them don't even put up ads, but I'm always wary of businesses where you can't figure out how they're paying their bills.

The best option I can think of is probably [NearlyFreeSpeech.NET](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/). They do an excellent job of hosting PHP stuff and their pricing structure means you'll probably pay less than 50¢ per month:

- 1¢ per day for the PHP
- 1¢ per megabyte per month for storage
- $1 per gigabyte transferred... dropping as your lifetime transfer counter rises

They're also on a pre-pay setup, so you get even more control over how much you pay. I've never found anyone else even close to what they offer.